# Angular Material Design how to fill a column vertically

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

How do I fill a column vertically. I currently have this app.

[image]

I want to spand the vertical items vertically to take the rest of the page. I have tried for hours reading the documents and checking other posts but I just don't knows what is wrong. I'm just started using angular material and I'm new to the concept of flex box.

this is my code.

```
<body ng-cloak layout="column" ng-app="app">
<div layout="row" flex>

    <md-sidenav layout="column" md-component-id="left" class="md-whiteframe-1dp" md-is-locked-open="true">
        <md-list>
            <md-list-item>
                <md-button ng-click="">
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">face</md-icon>
                    Alex
                </md-button>
            </md-list-item>
            <md-list-item>
                <md-button ng-click="">
                    <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons">face</md-icon>
                    Tara
                </md-button>
            </md-list-item>
        </md-list>
    </md-sidenav>

    <md-content flex id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium animi at consequuntur doloremque
            dolores
            dolorum eaque, exercitationem expedita facere fugiat ipsam nemo possimus quod recusandae repellendus, saepe
            sequi
            vitae, voluptas!
        </p>
    </md-content>

</div>
```

[Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/candoa/pen/ggPoKe?editors=1010#0)

I just notice that the parent div .app-wrapper causes the problem, but I want to keep it.

Comment: can you create plunker?

Comment: @user3862830 Here is a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/T8HaQ62IlEjXUWQpJo04?p=preview I created for you but I can see it going all the way to the bottom unlike your problem. Please update the plnkr to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added a code pen

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for `viewport height`. In your case, you could apply to `md-sidenav` via class:

```
.full-height{
    height: 100vh;
}
```